# JMeter API Testing - Recording the Incoming Traffic

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2, service-virtualization

Using JMeter, the HTTP Request is hitting a URL with the port.

Eg : apitesting.com:8888/api/series/one

I have also added a HTTP Test Script Recorder in JMeter, where I can mention the port and domain.

How do I import the incoming traffic to JMeter using tcpreplay and JMeter Proxy for the above example.

Thanks for your help in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the [FAQ](http://tcpreplay.synfin.net/wiki/FAQ#Doestcpreplaysupportsendingtraffictoaserver)?

> **Does tcpreplay support sending traffic to a server?**
>
> If by server you mean a daemon (Unix) or service (Windows) which listens on a port (a web or mail server would be common examples), then probably not. The biggest issue is that tcpreplay doesn't understand the state of common protocols like TCP. This means it is unable to synchronize Syn/Ack's to create valid TCP sessions.

So you have the following options:

- [Consider using Wireplay tool instead](https://github.com/abhisek/wireplay)
- Convert your .pcap file into JMeter .jmx script using [BlazeMeter JMX Converter](http://converter.blazemeter.com/)

In both cases be aware that you will get only a "skeleton" of the project, you won't be able to replay production traffic, all you will get would be a set of [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers, you will have to figure out the workload model on your own.

Answer (score 0):

In JMeter you can add to your HTTP request a Post Processor Named [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion), If you check the `Ignore Status` checkbox you will ignore response of the server so even if server is down it'll not fail test and continue.